# How to modify position or placement of an edge in graph drawing?

Tags: matplotlib, graph, networkx

Having this code to generate the drawing:

```
opt = { 'node_color': 'green',
     'node_size': 500,
     'width': 3,
     'with_labels': True }
coords =networkx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
networkx.draw(G, pos = coords, **opt) # create a drawing
labels = networkx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
networkx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos=coords,edge_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

And getting this result:

[image: Graph result]

I have the problem that, existing edges `[0,4], [5,9], [10,14], [15, 19]`, are not visible due to the distribution of the nodes. Is there a way to modify the geometry of those edges (before changing their color) to make them visible?

Here is the code I'm using to generate this graph:

```
N_orbital_planes = 4
N_satellites_plane = 5
G = networkx.Graph()
i=0
#Node generation
while(i<N_orbital_planes):
    j=0
    while(j<N_satellites_plane):
        G.add_node(j+i*N_satellites_plane,pos=(i,j))
        j=j+1 
    i = i + 1 
#Edges generation
i=0
while(i<N_orbital_planes):
    pt = i*N_satellites_plane
    j=0
    while(j<N_satellites_plane):
        if(j<N_satellites_plane-1):
            G.add_edge(pt+j,pt+j+1,weight=1, color='black')           
        if(i<N_orbital_planes-1):
            G.add_edge(pt+j,pt+j+N_satellites_plane,weight=2, color='black') 
        j = j+1
    G.add_edge(pt,(j+pt)-1,weight=1, color='black',headport='sw',tailport='nw') #Edge belonging to a latitude hop
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Could you provide a way to generate your graph G?

Comment: Sorry, posted it on the main @jylls , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is to draw curved edges instead of straight edges (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588453/creating-curved-edges-with-networkx-in-python3)) by using the argument `connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.3"` while drawing your graph. However, `connectionstyle` seems to only be implemented for directed graph (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588453/creating-curved-edges-with-networkx-in-python3)), which is fine if you only intend to draw the graph. In that case, you can use `G=nx.DiGraph()` instead of  `G=nx.Graph()`. And you can then use `connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.3",arrowstyle='-'` in the draw function.

See below for the code:

```py
import networkx as nx

N_orbital_planes = 4
N_satellites_plane = 5
G = nx.DiGraph()  ##change to directed graph
i=0
#Node generation
while(i<N_orbital_planes):
    j=0
    while(j<N_satellites_plane):
        G.add_node(j+i*N_satellites_plane,pos=(i,j))
        j=j+1 
    i = i + 1 
#Edges generation
i=0
while(i<N_orbital_planes):
    pt = i*N_satellites_plane
    j=0
    while(j<N_satellites_plane):
        if(j<N_satellites_plane-1):
            G.add_edge(pt+j,pt+j+1,weight=1, color='black')           
        if(i<N_orbital_planes-1):
            G.add_edge(pt+j,pt+j+N_satellites_plane,weight=2, color='black') 
        j = j+1
    G.add_edge(pt,(j+pt)-1,weight=1, color='black',headport='sw',tailport='nw') #Edge belonging to a latitude hop
    i = i+1
opt = { 'node_color': 'green',
     'node_size': 500,
     'width': 3,
     'with_labels': True }

coords =nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
nx.draw(G, pos = coords, connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.3",arrowstyle='-',**opt) #curve edges here
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos=coords,edge_labels=labels)
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using only for drawing purposes the graph. I'll try to investigate further this way.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No pbm! The stackoverflow post ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588453/creating-curved-edges-with-networkx-in-python3)) that I linked in my answer suggests a way to do curved edges with matplotlib annotations (instead of using `connectionstyle` on directed graphs). That might help